# How does the following get executed in Javascript, step by step?

Tags: javascript, scope, execution, iife

```js
var a;
console.log(a);

+function() {
  alert("Hello from IIFE!");
}();

console.log(a);
a = 'Hi';
```

Answer in console:
undefined
ALERT POPUP
Hi

Question: Either both a should be giving undefined or both should display Hi

How does the javascript work?

Executing in different ways

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing, but I'm getting both undefined

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Your assumption is right, both should be logged as `undefined`. And they are, when I run the code snippet ... Not sure what environment you are using or if there is some other code you are not showing us

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I got it!

Answer (score 0):

1. `a` is set to `undefined`.
2. `undefined` is logged.
3. alert is immediately invoked `"Hello from IIFE!"`
4. `undefined` is logged.
5. `a` is set to `'Hi'`

If you copy paste your own text in dev tools you'll see this pattern with a minor difference. In a new console session you'll get:

1. undefined
2. alert
3. undefined
4. 'Hi'

The last Hi, and I'm guessing the source of your confusion, is the return value from assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much Jensei! Yes, you are correct the return value in dev tools was the confusion!

Comment: Glad to hear it. By accepting the answer the question will appear resolved.